# Spring fetches lazy loaded objects during serialization

Tags: java, spring

I have the following entity:

```
@Data
public class Project {

  // attributes

  @OneToMany
  private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

So by default One To Many has a lazy fetchtype. I have an API-method which returns all projects.

```
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> getProjects() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.getProjects());
  }
```

Service:

```
List<Project> getProjects() {
  return projectRepository.findAll();
}
```

So i would expect and want `employees` not to be a part of the response, because of lazy fetching. But the response actually contains `employees`. Judging by the logged SQL statements, it seems like Spring fetches `employees` during serialization. The SQL statements to get the `employees` happen after the following line:

```
// gets the projects here
2019-12-23 13:46:03.759 DEBUG 9436 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
// gets the employees here
```

which marks the start of serialization.

How can i tell spring to ignore lazy loaded objects during serialization if i didn´t explicitally fetch them beforehand myself?

**EDIT:**

Spring fetches the objects inside this method inside the class `MethodSecurityInterceptor`:

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(mi);

    Object result;
    try {
      result = mi.proceed(); // this line causes it
    } finally {
      super.finallyInvocation(token);
    }

    return super.afterInvocation(token, result);
  }
```

Thats called after my code is executed, im not sure why and how to prevent that call.

Comment: If  `List<Project>` is send as json then you can add `@JsonIgnore`  on  'employees'. Or use DTO to send what you need: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: I tried that, but the SQL statements to fetch the `employees` are still executed that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you only send data, then use [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).
Add View for Project:

```java
public interface ProjectView {
/// getter that you want expose, for example
    String getName();
}
```

In projectRepository add:

```java
List<ProjectView> findAll();
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but is there no way to achieve it without using views/dtos?

Comment: i guess i could not expose the getter for `employees` in my entity. And if i need it, i could just return them with an SQL statement and return the `roles` in a seperate request. That seems less work than creating a view/dto, espacially if i need to calculate stuff which would result in a lot of converting if i used dtos.

Comment: @M.Dietz you could try use `@Transactional` on `getProjects` for example `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`. After that you can use `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Ok i got it finally, i had to annotate the class with lomboks `@ToString(exclude = {"employees"})` and the field with `@JsonIgnore`. So it seems like the field was lazily fetched when the objects toString method was called and when it was converted to JSON. I knew that the second case was a problem, but didn´t know that `toString` was called even if i already used @JsonIgnore. Is it because it calls toString to show the object in springs debugging message? Not sure where it would call toString otherwise.